# Unable to solve the error: Cannot open include file oci.h

Tags: node.js, windows, oracle, npm

I am installing the oracledb module but get this error:
Cannot open include file oci.h.
I have attached the picture of error as well.
I have all the prerequisites as mentioned at this website:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb
Although I am a bit confused about this part:
**Set OCI_LIB_DIR and OCI_INC_DIR during installation if the Oracle libraries and headers are in a non-default location**

How can i resolve this error??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I was able to solve the above issue by reading this article:   https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-931127                 But ran in to few more problems, as can be seen in this photo

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though your path is not setup correctly (pointing to the OCI libs). See these GitHub issues:
https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/304
https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/291

Comment: Thanks for it, but I got an error while installing, even though I have declared environment variables as well.
actually i solved the above issue, but got further error which I have mentioned in the Answer below.

LINK 2001:  unresolved external symbol

Comment: Could you please show your path output just prior to running the build?

Comment: 1) OCI_INC_DIR:  
C:\app\Umeriftikhar\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\OCI\include                      

2) OCI_LIB_DIR:    
C:\app\Umeriftikhar\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\OCI\lib\MSVC

I also installed instant client and tried giving its path as well, but got the same error:   Link 2001

Comment: By the way, Installed the 64-bit version of node.js and when I go and check it in TaskManager it show me 32-bit.
Could this be a problem?

Comment: You definitely need to have a consistent 64 or 32 bit stack.

Answer (score 0):

The first three compile warnings didn't occur with the VC version used in development but they will be addressed.  The lean&mean warning isn't coming from node-oracledb but I believe has already been noted.

The missing symbols indicate that your PATH doesn't correctly contain the directory with the Oracle libraries - or the correct version/architecture of the libraries.